# Socat: run script in bidirectional tunnel

Tags: tcp, exec, socat

I am running a tunnel like this:

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:9090,fork TCP:192.168.1.3:9090
```

I would like to run a script to execute code with the strings passing through the tunnel.

The script does not change the strings, only processes strings independently but allows passage without changing between both ends.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to even alter the communication using this approach:

Prepare a helper script `helper.sh` which gets executed for each connection:

```
#!/bin/bash

./inFilter.sh | socat - TCP:192.168.1.3:9090 | ./outFilter.sh
```

And start listening by using:

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:9090,fork EXEC:"./helper.sh"
```

The scripts `inFilter.sh` and `outFilter.sh` are processing the client and the server parts of the communication.

Example `inFilter.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r l ; do echo "IN(${l})" ; done
```

Example `outFilter.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r l ; do echo "OUT(${l})" ; done
```

---

This method should work for line-based text communication (as almost everything is [line-buffered](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Buffering-Concepts.html)).

To make it work for binary protocols wrapping all processes with `stdbuf -i0 -o0` might help (see .e.g [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe)) and getting rid of shell is probably a good idea in this case.

Good luck!